# Why would this design (Si8261BCC-IS) blow the chip?

Tags: mosfet-driver

I created a design for a simple MOSFET driver using the [Si8261BCC-IS](https://www.silabs.com/isolation/isolated-gate-drivers/si826x-isolated-gate-drivers/device.si8261bcc-is). The schematic and Gerber files are available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OrVLv4VfJS-6A83AF7Kemexxz-GgUZdO/view?usp=sharing). The schematic is also shown below. When I connect the input control signal of 3.3V at J1, the chip blows up. There is a proper flash of flame and then blue smoke. The supply voltage on the MOSFET side is 24V. Why would this be happening?

[image: Si8261BCC-IS based mosfet driver]

Comment: What happens to R2 and D1 when U2 drives Vo to VDD?

Comment: Just a note, \$\text{V}_{\text{DD}}\$ is typically your digital logic voltage, such as 5v or 3.3v. \$\text{V}_{\text{CC}}\$ is the higher voltage, such as 24v.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the troublesome part of the circuit is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB2ab2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the PMOS inside the Si8261 switches on, it connects **24 V** across R2 (4.7 ohm) and the 12 V zener diode. So in theory, that means there would be about 12 V across R2 so 12 V / 4.7 ohm = **2.55 A** wants to flow. That's much more than that poor PMOS can handle. Check the datasheet to see what it can actually handle.

Even if the PMOS could handle the current, R2 and the zener diode would blow up eventually due to excess power dissipation (the zener and R2 each get: 12 V * 2.55 A = **30 W** OUCH!!! the magic smoke will escape in a nano second)

I would give R2 a **significantly** higher value in the order of 1 kohm or more. Then calculate the maximum current that can flow through R2 and make sure the power dissipation ratings of R2 and D1 are not exceeded. Of course the current must be within the range that the Si8261's internal PMOS can handle.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed explanation. I re-read the datasheet and found that the "Output High Current (Source) or I(OH)" is typically 1.8A for Si826xBxx devices. R2 is rated for 100mW and D1 is rated at 500mW. With a 2K resistor, the current through R2 would be 6mA, and power dissipated across it would be 72mW. However, would this not affect the switching speed of the MOSFET?

Comment: @electrophile this would affect switching speed indeed. You can calculate it based on total gate charge/capacity. If you need faster switching you need a better 12V source. Via linear or switching step-down regulators.

Comment: *However, would this not affect the switching speed of the MOSFET?* Yes, I agree with NStorm. But before you do your best to make the switching "as fast as possible", try to determine what switching speed you actually **need**. You're switching a heating element which has a heat capacity making it slow, i.e. it doesn't care much about how fast you switch on/off. Switching on/off slowly does increase power dissipation in the MOSFET (when it is not fully on//off) so also don't switch too slowly. My guess is that R2 = 2 kohm will work just fine and is fast enough.

Comment: Got it. The MOSFET will be switching a solenoid for a PNP machine. So switching speed is really not a constraint for this application.

Comment: So I assembled a new board with a 2k resistor and now the chip does not blow but the load won't turn on. Also just looked at their [EVB](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2244965.pdf) and there is a 4.7-ohm res on the output.

Comment: *Also just looked at their EVB and there is a 4.7-ohm res on the output* But is there a zenerdiode? Did you bridge jumper JP1? Are all the voltages what they should be? I'm afraid you need to put a bit more effort into understanding how the circuit works. If you think that the 4.7 ohm resistor vs a 2 k resistor causes your load not to turn on/off then you clearly do not understand how the circuit (should) work(s).

Comment: Yep I don’t understand how it works. There is no zener on the EVB. With the 2k resistor the voltage across the zener that I measured is 6V. How can that be? This means that the drop across the resistor is 18V. Clearly I’m missing something.

Comment: Check (see datasheet) how much current the zenerdiode needs for the correct zener voltage. What type is the NMOS, does it have a build-in zenerdiode (some MOSFETs do)?

Comment: The Zener is a [DDZ12CSF-7](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds31987.pdf) which requires 10mA to be fully operational. The NMOS is [NTD5865NL-D](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NTD5865NL-D.PDF). It does not have an inbuilt Zener on the gate. This means that a minimum of 10mA should flow through the resistor as well. That calculates R2 to (24-12)/10m = 1.2K. Is this correct?

Comment: *That calculates R2 to (24-12)/10m = 1.2K. Is this correct?* Yes, I think so. Also don't forget to re calculate the power dissipation again in resistor and zener and check if their power rating is OK for that.

Answer (score 2):

The chip tries to set the output high to 24V. Since the FET gate can't handle 24V, there is a 12V zener to clamp voltage and the 4.7R resistor that limits the current to about 2.5A. The chip is not meant to drive out that much DC current, and it heats up and gets damaged.